# IF user geolocation is inside a polygone THEN open URL

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am trying to create a treasure hunt game for my son in a park. I would like to create a website with a Google/Mapbox map with a geolocation anable. When we arrive in an area of the park (polygone that i created), a new webpage will open automaticaly.

I think it would be  :

IF geolocation point is inside a polygone THEN open new URL.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

```js
/* Getting HTML Geolocation */

if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          };

/* Making Polygon Object */

const polygonCoords = [
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
    { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
    { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
  ]; // coordinates of park
  const myPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: polygonCoords });
  
/* Checking if Location is within Polygon */

if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(pos, myPolygon) {
  //Open Webpage
}
```

The Google Maps API doesn't update geolocation automatically, so you would have to refresh the page once you reach the park, which would then redirect you to the new URL. [More documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)